# $A\bar{B}$ is normal if and only if there is a unitary $U \in M_n$ such that $A = U \Sigma U^T$, $B = U \Lambda U^T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in M_n$ be symmetric. Show that $A\bar{B}$ is normal if and only if there is a unitary $U \in M_n$ such that $A = U \Sigma U^T$, $B = U \Lambda U^T$, $\Sigma, \Lambda \in M_n$ are diagonal and the diagonal entries of $\Sigma$ are nonnegative.

---

I am able to prove that $A\bar{B}$ is normal given a unitary $U \in M_n$ such that $A = U \Sigma U^T$, $B = U \Lambda U^T$, $\Sigma, \Lambda \in M_n$ are diagonal and the diagonal entries of $\Sigma$ are nonnegative.

---

I am facing difficulty in proving the other direction.

Comment: The combination of unitary matrices an **symmetric** matrices is a bit strange (though consistent with results like [Takagi's factorizaiton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Takagi's_factorization)), so please clarify your notation. Is $M_n$ the set of matrix with *complex* entries? Should $A,B$ be symmetric or Hermitian? Does $U^T$ denote the entry-wise transpose or the conjugate-transpose?

Comment: @BenGrossmann $M_n$ is the set of matrices with complex entries and $U^T$ means transpose of the matrix, not conjugate transpose.

Comment: @BenGrossmann $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, not hermitian.